# Uniform convergence of Taylor series for arcsin(x)

Tags: real-analysis

After proving $$  \ \arcsin{x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {c_n}{2n+1}{x^{2n+1}} $$ $\forall x\in(-1,1)$ where $c_n=\frac {(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^{2}}$

Since $\arcsin{x}$ continuous on $[-1,1]$, explain why the Taylor series for $\arcsin{x}$ converges uniformly to $\arcsin{x}$ on $[-1,1]$.

---

The context of this question is; after deriving $E_n(x)=1/N!\int_{0}^{x}f^{n+1}(t)(x-t)^ndt $.

I let $f_n(x)= \frac {c_n}{2n+1}{x^{2n+1}}\leq\frac {c_n}{2n+1}{k^{2n+1}}=M_n$ where $k\geq x,  \lvert{k}\rvert<1$

Then I used ratio test on $M_n$ for $(0,1)$ and Raabe's test for the endpoints. For uniform convergence I used M-test. This process yields the proof of uniform convergence.

---

But I have found this solution to be rather unsatisfactory, Is there an alternate proof of this fact without using a convergence test, for example, *using* $E_n(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

It is known that
$$
c_n  \le \frac{1}{{\sqrt {\pi n} }}
$$
for all $n\geq 1$. Hence, for $-1\leq x \leq 1$,
\begin{align*}
\left| {\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{c_n }}{{2n + 1}}x^{2n + 1} } } \right| & \le \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{c_n }}{{2n + 1}}\left| x \right|^{2n + 1} }  \le \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{c_n }}{{2n + 1}}} \\ & \le 1 + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {\pi n} }}\frac{1}{{2n + 1}}}  \le 1 + \frac{1}{{2\sqrt \pi  }}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n^{3/2} }}}  <  + \infty .
\end{align*}
Thus, the series converges absolutely and uniformly for all $-1\leq x \leq 1$.